# using comparative operators in string slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lambda

I was following a tutorial and got stuck at this interesting string slicing part. Suppose I have string s,

```
s='-123'
```

and trying to take a subset of the string using,

```
s[s[0] == '-':]
```

What is the purpose of using comparative operator == in the slicing part and what will be the resulting string?

The complete code is here:

```
def string_to_int(s):
    return functools.reduce(lambda running_sum, c: running_sum * 10 + 
         string.digits.index(c), s[s[0] == '-':], 0) * (-1 if s[0] == '-' else 1)
```

Comment: think of it like `s[1:] if s.startswith('-') else s`

Comment: frankly the `string_to_int` is horribly non-readable IMO, not sure why this would be used in a tutorial!

Answer (score 4):

`s[0] == '-'` will evaluate to `True` for strings beginning with `-` and `False` otherwise. `True` has a numeric value of `1`, `False` `0`, so the effect is to slice from index `1` onwards when it begins with `-` (skipping the `-`) or from `0` onwards otherwise (skipping nothing since there is no `-`).

Essentially, this is an overly clever way of stripping exactly one leading `-` from a string, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see.

```
s[0] == '-'
```

That means "is the first char of the string the "-" symbol ? In your case, that's `True`, and `True` is equivalent to `1`.

If you replace that by one, you can understand better :

```
s[1:]
```

So it will returns all the string but the first char.

BUT ! If it was `False`, like in `s = "+123"`, then as `False` is equivalent to `0`, it will returns the entire string.